# How to seach a list of customers in java using Scanner:

Tags: java

Can anyone help me please?
I'm working on this assignment and I'm almost done with my code, except that I don't know how to search the list of customers by typing their names. !

- Get a list of customers from a file
- Customer contains first name, last name, and email address
- Sort the list by last name
- **Search the list for a given name**
- List item

  ```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class computer {


  public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

      //create a file named myFile.txt
      createFile object1 = new  createFile();
      object1.openFile();
      object1.addRecords();
      object1.closeFile();

      //This code reads the File and outputs it on the screen
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------"); 
      System.out.println("This is the list of customers being read from a file called myFile.txt ");
      System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
      readFile r = new readFile();
      r.openFile();
      r.readfile();
      r.closeFile();


      LinkedList<customers> list = new LinkedList<customers>();
      try
      {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("myFile.txt"));
        while(file.hasNext())
        {
          String name = file.next();
          String lname = file.next();
          String email = file.next();
          list.add(new customers(name,lname, email));
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO: handle exception
      }
      Collections.sort(list,new Mycustomers());
      System.out.println("This is the list of customers sorted by their last names: ");
      System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println();
      for(customers cu:list){
          System.out.println(cu);
      }
  ```

Comment: Which customers do you need to search for? Are they the same ones each time, being read from a file, or does the user specify which customers to search for? The question you are stuck on has two parts. One is getting the names to search for. This part could use `Scanner`. The other is actually performing the searching. This should not use `Scanner.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with how you print the list, but instead printing every one, first compare the name in each with the name you are looking for (can't give more detail without more details on `customers`); if it matches, do whatever you need to do and `break` the loop.

To read in what name to search for, I'll repeat what user3567040 said:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
String name =s.nextLine();
```

(although you might need 2 `Strings`: one for the first name, and another for the last.

Comment: This is how I print the list of customers, and the list of customers can be any  3 random people. This is the code ............public String toString(){
        return "First Name: "+this.name+"\nLast Name: "+this.lastName + "\nEmail: "+this.email+"\n";
    }

Comment: But how to search them :(

Comment: I think I need to use Scanner but Im not sure how

Comment: @Henry: You have already read them & put them into `list`; you used `Scanner` to put them in there.

Comment: The customers are in the list, but I need to allow the user to type the name of the customer for example Michael White...and how to do that? heres a link of my entire code pastebin.com/yArT5ww9

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashTable or HashMap with the key as the Hash of the first + last name. And Search according to the hash of the entered given name.

Comment: I need to use Scanner , but I'm not sure how

Comment: Doesn't address the problem of how to get them *in* there; and they're already in a list.

Comment: The customers are in the list, but I need to allow the user to type the name of the customer for example Michael White...and how to do that? heres a link of my entire code http://pastebin.com/yArT5ww9

Comment: Are you asking how to use Scanner class to get the input from the user? in that case Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); String name =s.nextLine();